# Are [policy] and [rules] the same thing?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

Here on meta, we have two tags, [rules](/questions/tagged/rules) and [policy](/questions/tagged/policy). They seem pretty much to be the same thing - the words are basically synonyms.

Should we merge these? If so, which should be the main tag and which should be the synonym?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they are!

M E R G E D.